# Mongodb text index Duplicate Key Error when part of string field same

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, database

For examples:

doc1:

```
{
'name':'apple'
}
```

doc2:

```
{
'name':'apple juice'
}
```

when I create text index with pymongo:

```
db.products_collection.create_index([('name', TEXT)],
                                     unique=True,
                                    background=True)
```

it give me an error:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: c.items_collection index:
>   name_text_alias_text dup key: { : "apple", : 10.5 }

Some one know why? I cannot add `unique=True` for text string?

Comment: `apple` and `apple juice` are two different values. They can not cause your error, you should check your db for any occurrences

Comment: I know what you mean. What the problems is the text index. I think mongodb use ' ' to split string to index to improve search and make this error happen. You can try with the text index.

Comment: I think I got a solution.

Comment: How do you solve it?

Comment: @Khang do not use one index but two indexes.

Comment: One for text index, one for name only

Comment: Be more clear, one index be UNIQUE to guarantee all values are unique, one for TEXT for helping search.

Answer (score 3):

A text index splits strings into tokens (words), and those tokens form the keys. So in your example, "apple" is a duplicates key.

Generally, unique text index is the bad idea.

Comment: please review the comments of questions.