# Duplicate key error with mongodb text index

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing

I want to setup a unique text index in mongodb.  I have the default '_id' field, and I want to set an index on my custom field 'database_tag'.

First, I find any duplicate documents by aggregating on my field, counting the aggregates, and matching the returned documents with counts > 1. Then I delete the duplicate object ids

```
a = collection.aggregate([
        {'$group':{
                '_id':{'database_tag':'$database_tag'},
                'dups':{'$push':'$_id'},
                'count':{'$sum':1}
                }
        },
        {'$match': {
                'count':{'$gt':1}
                }
        }
        ])

for document in a:
    #Get the collection ids
    ids = document['dups']

    #Choose the trailing ids and delete
    for dupid in ids[:-1]:
        ack = collection.delete_one({'_id':dupid})
        if ack:
            print(f'{dupid} deleted')
        else:
            print(f'{dupid} not found')
```

I then try to create an index on my tag :

```
collection.create_index([('database_tag',pymongo.TEXT)], 
                         name='custom_index',
                         unique=True,
                         default_language='none')
```

I get the standard DuplicateKeyError

> DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: >master_points.raw_databases index: custom_index dup key: { _fts: >"134749_acc_jcp_highland_mall"

OK.. so I find documents matching the key I saw.

```
bb = collection.find({'database_tag':{'$regex':'134749'}})
for document in bb:
    print(document['database_tag'])


>>> D:\Z - Saved SQL Databases\_old_44OP-134749_ACC_JCP_Highland_Mall\JobDB.mdf
>>> D:\Z - Saved SQL Databases\44OP-134749_ACC_JCP_Highland_Mall\JobDB.mdf
```

OK it looks like it has to deal with similar text

from the documentation :

> For tokenization, version 3 text index uses the delimiters categorized under >Dash, Hyphen, Pattern_Syntax, Quotation_Mark, Terminal_Punctuation, and >White_Space

I'm not 100% sure what this means, but it seems related.  Can someone describe why my method does not work, and is there a better solution?

edit : I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499611/mongodb-text-index-duplicate-key-error-when-part-of-string-field-same) related question. It lacks a good resolution/workaround.  The goal of this question is to provide a workaround

Comment: Unique index searches the data more like google. It just looks for matching keyword. So if you've the same key word (even a part) in second document, it'll return both the documents. Building unique text index in your use case wouldn't be the right choice as I can see the strings can duplicate